# Groovy to round all array decimal places down and return unique number count?

Tags: groovy

Thank you aspok for your help!

My goal is to get my list to be `[3, 3, 4]` and then get a count of unique values within it. Can anyone point me in the right direction for doing this?

My script consumes a JSON and puts all F4211_LNID values into a list. `[3.1, 3.9, 4]`. I need to now round all decimal places down.

I'm not sure if it's doable, but I am trying to use `Math.floor(intListItems)` to round my array values down. When I try this I receive the following error: `Exception No signature of method: static java.lang.Math.floor() is applicable for argument types: (ArrayList) values: [[3.1, 3.9, 4]] Possible solutions: floor(double), log(double), find(), macro(groovy.lang.Closure), acos(double), cos(double)`

I see my simplified list in the error, but I can't get it to round down and not sure what the error means.

(UPDATED) My Working Groovy

```
   // Read Input Values
  String aInputJson = aInputMap.InputJson ?: "{}"
   
  // Initialize Output Values
  def intListItems = []
  def uniqueCount = 0 
    
  // Parse JSON
  def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText( aInputJson )
    
  // Determine Row Numbers
  def rowset = json?.fs_DATABROWSE_F4211?.data?.gridData?.rowset
  
  intListItems = rowset.collect{ Math.floor(it.F4211_LNID) }
    
  intListItems.unique()
    
  uniqueCount = intListItems.size()
```

JSON I am using.

```
{
  "fs_DATABROWSE_F4211": {
    "title": "Data Browser - F4211 [Sales Order Detail File]",
    "data": {
      "gridData": {
        "id": 58,
        "fullGridId": "58",
        "rowset": [
          {
            "F4211_LNTY": "S",
            "F4211_CPNT": 0,
            "F4211_MCU": "      114000",
            "F4211_DSC2": "NAS133N3EK166",
            "F4211_NXTR": "580",
            "F4211_LNID": 3.1,
            "F4211_DOCO": 2845436
          },
          {
            "F4211_LNTY": "S",
            "F4211_CPNT": 0,
            "F4211_MCU": "      114000",
            "F4211_DSC2": "NAS133N3EK166",
            "F4211_NXTR": "580",
            "F4211_LNID": 3.9,
            "F4211_DOCO": 2845436
          },
          {
            "F4211_LNTY": "S",
            "F4211_CPNT": 0,
            "F4211_MCU": "      114000",
            "F4211_DSC2": "NAS133N3EK166",
            "F4211_NXTR": "580",
            "F4211_LNID": 4,
            "F4211_DOCO": 2845436
          }
        ],
        "summary": {
          "records": 1,
          "moreRecords": false
        }
      }
    },
    "errors": [],
    "warnings": []
  },
  "currentApp": "DATABROWSE_F4211",
  "timeStamp": "2000-06-01:09.42.02",
  "sysErrors": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error `Exception No signature of method: static java.lang.Math.floor() is applicable for argument types: (ArrayList)` because there is no version of `Math.floor()` that accepts a List as a parameter.

Instead, you need to call `Math.floor()` on each individual item in the list. The easiest way to do this is in the `collect { }` call you are already doing.

```
def flooredList = rowset.collect { Math.floor(it.F4211_LNID) }
assert flooredList == [3.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked to round down my values. I was able to update my code to the below and get the unique count using `intListItems.unique()`. I update my man code for the post to reflect it.